# Getting SimpleTypeImpl should not be created for error type on migrating groovy to kotlin

Tags: android-studio, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have recently migrated my app which contains multiple modules from groovy to kotlin. All the modules have been migrated successfully expect app module. To verify the same, i have run the app on the emulator after each module migration. On migrating build.gradle (module:app) to kotlin, it shows java.lang.IllegalStateException: SimpleTypeImpl should not be created for error type:ErrorScope error after migratinon.

**Error**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: SimpleTypeImpl should not be created for error type: ErrorScope{Error scope for class <Error class: unknown class> with arguments: org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.IndexedParametersSubstitution@604410ed}
[Error type: Type for error type constructor (Result)]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.SimpleTypeImpl.<init>(KotlinTypeFactory.kt:230)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.KotlinTypeFactory.simpleTypeWithNonTrivialMemberScope(KotlinTypeFactory.kt:161)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.KotlinTypeFactory.simpleType(KotlinTypeFactory.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.KotlinTypeFactory.simpleType$default(KotlinTypeFactory.kt:77)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.TypeSubstitutionKt.replace(TypeSubstitution.kt:174)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.TypeSubstitutionKt.replace(TypeSubstitution.kt:159)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.TypeSubstitutionKt.replace$default(TypeSubstitution.kt:142)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.util.TypeUtilsKt.replaceAnonymousTypeWithSuperType(typeUtils.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.KaptAnonymousTypeTransformer.transformAnonymousType(KaptAnonymousTypeTransformer.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.DescriptorResolver.transformAnonymousTypeIfNeeded(DescriptorResolver.java:1069)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.DescriptorResolver.lambda$inferReturnTypeFromExpressionBody$5(DescriptorResolver.java:1303)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:408)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:527)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.DeferredType.getDelegate(DeferredType.java:108)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.WrappedType.getAttributes(KotlinType.kt:135)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.KotlinType.getAnnotations(KotlinType.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.forceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:109)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.doForceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.forceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.forceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.forceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.doForceResolveAllContents(LazyClassDescriptor.java:717)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.lambda$new$4(LazyClassDescriptor.java:224)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:408)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.forceResolveAllContents(LazyClassDescriptor.java:705)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.doForceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:78)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.forceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension$doAnalysis$1.invoke(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:73)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension$doAnalysis$1.invoke(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doForEachDeclaration(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:126)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doForEachDeclaration(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:141)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doAnalysis(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.doAnalysis(Kapt3Extension.kt:157)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:123)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:257)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:248)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:167)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:485)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:131)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.doCompile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:424)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:360)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileNonIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:242)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:625)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1746)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

**build.gradle.kts (module:app)**

```
plugins {
    id ("com.android.application")
    id ("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id ("com.google.devtools.ksp")
    id ("kotlin-kapt")
    id ("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
    id ("kotlin-parcelize")
    id ("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.6.10"
    id ("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin")
    id ("com.google.gms.google-services")
    id ("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
    }

    android {
    compileSdk = 34
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "................."
        minSdk = 23
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 209
        versionName = "4.8.29"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }
    bundle {
        storeArchive {
            enable = false
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isDebuggable = false
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
            proguardFiles (
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), 
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
            ndk {
                debugSymbolLevel = "full"
            }
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("debug")
            isDebuggable = true
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            isShrinkResources = false
            proguardFiles (
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), 
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
            buildConfigField ("String", "ACCESS_ID", ".............................")
            buildConfigField ("String", "SECRET_KEY",".............................")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
    lint {
        checkReleaseBuilds = false
    }
    ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
    namespace = ".........................."
    applicationVariants.forEach { variant ->
        val name = variant.name
        kotlin.sourceSets {
            getByName(name) { kotlin.srcDirs(file("build/generated/ksp/${name}/kotlin")) }
        }
    }
    }

    dependencies {



    implementation ("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1")
    implementation ("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.4.3")
    implementation ("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.4.3")
    implementation ("androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.3")
    implementation ("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.4.3")
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1")
    implementation ("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.6.1")

    implementation ("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation ("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation ("androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.6")
    testImplementation ("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation ("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation ("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation ("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.4.3")
    debugImplementation ("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.4.3")
    debugImplementation ("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.4.3")

    implementation ("com.google.android.play:app-update-ktx:2.1.0")

    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation( platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.5.0"))

    // Declare the dependencies for the Firebase Cloud Messaging and Analytics libraries
    // When using the BoM, you don"t specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics")
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx")
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx:21.4.1")

    // Google Maps
    implementation ("com.google.maps.android:maps-compose:2.2.1")
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0")

    // Work Manager
    implementation ("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.1")

    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.45")
    kapt ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.45")

    implementation ("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0")
    implementation ("androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0")
    kapt ("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0")

    // Location
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1")

    // Camerax ######## keep the version same
    implementation( "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.3.0-beta02")
    implementation ("androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.3.0-beta02")
    implementation ("androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.0-beta02")

    // Paging Compose
    implementation ("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.27.0")
    implementation ("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:0.27.0")

    // Paging 3
    implementation("androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.2.0")
    implementation("androidx.paging:paging-compose:3.2.0")


    // Data Store (Shared Preferences)
    implementation ("androidx.datastore:datastore:1.0.0")
    implementation ("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0")
    implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.3")

    // Compose dependencies
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.1")
    implementation ("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.4.3")
    implementation ("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-flowlayout:0.27.0")
    implementation ("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-swiperefresh:0.27.0")

    // Compose Nav Destinations
    implementation ("io.github.raamcosta.compose-destinations:core:1.7.21-beta")
    ksp ("io.github.raamcosta.compose-destinations:ksp:1.7.21-beta")

    // Retrofit
    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
    implementation ("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.11.0")
    implementation ("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.11.0")

    // Room
    implementation ("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.2")
    implementation ("androidx.room:room-paging:2.5.2")
    ksp ("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2")


    // Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation ("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.2")

    // Permission Library
    implementation ("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-permissions:0.27.0")


    // Mapbox
    implementation ("com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-turf:5.8.0")

    // Rating Bar
    implementation ("com.github.a914-gowtham:compose-ratingbar:1.2.4")

    // Glide
    implementation ("com.github.skydoves:landscapist-glide:2.2.2")
    implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.15.1")
    ksp ("com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.15.1")

    implementation ("com.gu.android:toolargetool:0.3.0")

    // AWS
    implementation ("com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.55.0")
    implementation ("com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.6.17")

    // jetpack compose navigation
    implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.6.0")

    // In-app review
    implementation("com.google.android.play:review-ktx:2.0.1")

    // Graph
    implementation ("com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:3.1.0")

}
```